# How to update my procfile and push it to Heroku to replace the current one?

Tags: django, heroku

Just pushed my first Django app to Heroku, but my Dynos is blank.  It doesn't appear to be detecting my procfile.  I want to re-do my procfile and push it to my app to replace the current one.  Once I make a new procfile in my text editor, how do I push it to my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is how to push an updated file to Heroku. As heroku supports GIT so essentially you want help on GIT.

As you already pushed your procfile to Heroku now you want to update it. So follow below steps -

```
$ git add Procfile
$ git commit -m "updating procfile"
$ git push heroku origin
```

Here I am assuming that your procfile is located at root folder.

For your Dyno problem.. can you let me know the output of commands

```
$ heroku ps
```

and

```
$heroku restart
```

Comment: Heroku was not looking at my Procfile but rather the main value set in mypackage.json